# Scala spark: extract columns from a schema

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a schema that looks following:

```
 |-- contributors: map (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- key: string
 |    |    |-- value: array (valueContainsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- type: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
```

I would like to have a dataframe that have the columns `key`, `name` and `id`

I have used the following code to get `name` and `id` but how do I get the column `key`?

```
df.select(explode(col("contributors")))
  .select(explode(col("value")))
  .select(col("col.*"))
```

**Update**

I tried to apply the first solution to the following schema but the compiler does not like it. I would like to get `value._name` and `subgenres.element.value._name`

```
         |-- mainGenre: struct (nullable = true)
         |    |-- value: struct (nullable = true)
         |    |    |-- _name: string (nullable = true)
         |    |-- subgenres: array (nullable = true)
         |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
         |    |    |    |-- value: struct (nullable = true)
         |    |    |    |    |-- type: string (nullable = true))
         |    |    |    |    |-- _name: string (nullable = true)
         |    |    |    |-- name: map (nullable = true)
         |    |    |    |    |-- key: string
         |    |    |    |    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = true)
```

I tried to create a variable with `value._name` and then insert it in my second variable like this.

```
val col_mainGenre_name = df_r.select(col("mainGenre.*"))
                             .select(col("value.*"))
                             .select(col("_name"))
                             .drop("readableName")
                             .drop("description")

val df_exploded = df_r.select(col("mainGenre.*"))
                      .select(col_mainGenre_name, col("value.*"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `key` column in your second and third select. `select` method of dataframe accepts several columns as argument.

You should modify your code as follows:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, explode}

df.select(explode(col("contributors")))
  .select(col("key"), explode(col("value")))
  .select(col("key"), col("col.*"))
```

With the following `contributors` input column:

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|contributors                                                                                |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|{key1 -> [{type11, name11, id11}, {type12, name12, id12}], key2 -> [{type21, name21, id21}]}|
|{key3 -> [{type31, name31, id31}, {type32, name32, id32}], key4 -> []}                      |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

You get the following ouput:

```
+----+------+------+----+
|key |type  |name  |id  |
+----+------+------+----+
|key1|type11|name11|id11|
|key1|type12|name12|id12|
|key2|type21|name21|id21|
|key3|type31|name31|id31|
|key3|type32|name32|id32|
+----+------+------+----+
```

if you want to keep only `name` and `id` columns from value, you should also modify the last `select` to select only `col.id` and `col.name` columns:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, explode}

df.select(explode(col("contributors")))
  .select(col("key"), explode(col("value")))
  .select(col("key"), col("col.name"), col("col.id"))
```

With the same `contributors` column input, you get your expected ouput:

```
+----+------+----+
|key |name  |id  |
+----+------+----+
|key1|name11|id11|
|key1|name12|id12|
|key2|name21|id21|
|key3|name31|id31|
|key3|name32|id32|
+----+------+----+
```

Comment: I wrote a update with a new schema. Is there any way to solve this? The first method is does not seems to be applicable.